# Android: Press Home Button in Child Activity to kill Parent Activity

Tags: android

I'm having an activity A which starts another activity B, I use the startActivityForResult method.
My plan is:
When I press Home button in activity B, I want Activity A to be killed as well.
In the onStop() of activity B, I tried setResult(1,mIntent) and in activity A, when request code ==1, I finish A.

However, when I press home button in B, the setResult method didn't get called.

I'm just wondering anybody knows why is that or is there another way to kill parent activity in child activity when home button pressed?

Answer (score 0):

Try the onUserLeaveHint method:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserLeaveHint%28%29

It executes when the user forces an activity to stop by, for example, clicking the home button

Comment: Thanks for the replying. I tryied the onUserLeaveHint method, and it got called when i press HOME. The problem is setResult() doesn't get called. I don't know how to interact with the parent activity apart from the setResult() method.

Comment: Actually the setResult() got called, but the onActivityResult() didn't get called. when I lauch the app again, the onActivityResult get called.